# Prevent onProgressUpdate() data from beeen lost after Fragment detach()

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, fragment

Currently im using a simple Fragment with a attached AsyncTask and  `setRetainInstance(true)` to handle runtime configuration changes and a callback interface to the MainActivity straight from the AsyncTask. ([following this example](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html)). This works fine so far.

But my Problem is that the data `onProgressUpdate` passes, once the fragment is detached (when switching to the home-screen for example) is lost. My soloution would be to create buffer variables inside the Fragment which store the lost data from the AsyncTask until the fragment is attached again.

```
 
public class MyFragment extends SherlockFragment {
```

`static interface TaskCallbacks {
    void onPreExecute();
    void onProgressUpdate(MyUpdateBundle p);
    void onCancelled();
    void onPostExecute();
  }

  private TaskCallbacks mCallbacks;
  private WebFetcherTask mTask;   
  public List<MyUpdateBundle> updateBuffer;

  public MyFragment() {
        this.updateBuffer = new ArrayList<MyUpdateBundle>();
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
  }

  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    mCallbacks = (TaskCallbacks) activity;

    if(updateBuffer.size() > 0)
    {
        for(MyUpdateBundle update : updateBuffer)
            mCallbacks.onProgressUpdate(update);

        updateBuffer.clear();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mCallbacks = null;
  }  
  ...
  private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, MyUpdateBundle, Void> {
  ...
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(MyUpdateBundle... uB) {
      if (mCallbacks != null) {
            for(MyUpdateBundle u : uB)
                mCallbacks.onProgressUpdate(u); 
      }
      else
      {
           for(MyUpdateBundle u : uB)
               updateBuffer.add(p); 
      }  
    }
  ...`

This seems to me the most cleanest soloution, beside saving the data (sinch this is very slow) or using StickyBroadcasts (doesn't seems a clean approach to me). I think that a Service would be a good alternative, but I'm not sure if I would end up in the same problem as here: **prevent data from been lost when everthing is unable to recieve.** However when I want to re-send the UpdateBundles within the `onAtach()` methode of the fragment, **the buffer is always empty.**

I've tryed so far:

- `volatile` statement on the updateBuffer List
- Collections.synchronizedList on the updateBuffer List
- ensured that the fragment is no create again/twice
- put the updateBuffer within the AsyncTask
- ...

But before I put too much time into this, I would like to know if my approach is even possible and when how.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Anyway I fixed it. I attached the AsyncTask to the application task and completly removed the Fragment.

It's also a great way to handle any configuration changes or vanished activitys. I don't need to save any data, I just read my buffers and pass them to the callback and have the **exact** same state as before!